# GROUP BY и подзапросы

Tags: sql, sql-server

#### Суть:

Задача собрать статистику по задачам и в каждый столбец собрать количество задач определенного типа
Группировка задач по пользователю

```
SELECT
    u.FullName,
    (SELECT COUNT(tb.id)) as 'TaskSum',
    (SELECT COUNT(tb.id) WHERE tb.[Status] in ({#EnumSQL.TaskBaseStatus.Incomplete}) GROUP BY tb.[Status]) as 'TaskOverdue'
    --TODO: More types
FROM TaskBase as tb
INNER JOIN [User] as u ON u.Id = tb.Executor
WHERE u.Status = 0 AND (tb.IsEmulation IS NULL OR tb.IsEmulation = 0)
GROUP BY tb.Executor, u.FullName
ORDER BY FullName asc
```

#### Проблема:

При добавлении статуса в подзапросы, то он требуется в `GROUP BY` или агрегатной функции т.е. 
`Столбец "TaskBase.Status" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.`

#### Что я пробовал :

1. Добавить `tb.status` в `GROUP BY` внутри подзапроса, то ошибка не уйдет
2. Добавить `tb.status` в `GROUP BY`то получим результат на скриншоте ниже, что не соответствует требованиям
3. Убрать `GROUP BY` из основного запроса и вынести `u.FullName` в подзапрос вместе с `GROUP BY` `(SELECT u.FullName GROUP BY tb.Executor) - не сработало`
4. Как и 3-ий пункт, только заместо `GROUP BY` - `DISTINCT` т.е. `(SELECT DISTINCT u.FullName)`

[image: Дубликаты при добавлении tb.status в GROUP BY]

#### Вопрос :

Как работать с `GROUP BY` и с подзапросами, что бы составить запрос из раздела 'Суть'

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), особое внимание пунктам 5 и 3. И никаких скриншотов, только форматированный текст/код/таблица.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо учту в будущем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда нужно подсчитать количество строк, но не всех, а только попадающих под некоторое условие, бывает достаточно замены оператора `COUNT` на оператор `SUM` по следующему шаблону:

```
-- COUNT(*)
SUM(CASE WHEN <условие> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Соответственно, в Вашем случае запрос примет такой вид:

```
SELECT
    u.FullName,
    COUNT(tb.id) as 'TaskSum',
    SUM(CASE WHEN tb.[Status] in ({#EnumSQL.TaskBaseStatus.Incomplete}) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TaskOverdue'
    -- TODO: More types
FROM TaskBase as tb
INNER JOIN [User] as u ON u.Id = tb.Executor
WHERE u.Status = 0 AND (tb.IsEmulation IS NULL OR tb.IsEmulation = 0)
GROUP BY tb.Executor, u.FullName
ORDER BY FullName asc
```

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN условие THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ` в целом тоже достаточно )

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN условие THEN 1 END)` - и так тоже норм )

Comment: Спасибо большое